# How to escape an ampersand in TypoScript/TYPO3?

Tags: html, encoding, typo3, typoscript

In my .ts file in TYPO3 4.5 I want to write `&auml;` to output an umlaut in the HTML output. But I only get `&amp;auml;`:

Shortened code from my TypoScript to make the intention clear:

```
page.meta.keywords = Hello &auml; World
```

generates in the output "& amp;auml;" instead of "ä".

How can I escape the ampersand in Typoscript?

Answer (score 1):

Try to just use `Ä`. It generates the special char code for most chars by its own. (That is also the reason why it replaces `&` with `&amp;`)

Comment: Then I get a question mark in the generated code. Must be some file encoding problem. Butdue to other reasons I am not allowed to change the file encoding for my .ts files.